# Query JCR SQL2 in Magnolia with a multivalue where-condition

Tags: magnolia, jcr-sql2

We are implementing a custom REST endpoint in magnolia that queries for pages and it should be able to filter by categories. I found the [JCR Query Cheat Sheet](https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/JCR+Query+Cheat+Sheet), but I could not see an example about filtering a multivalued field. In our case, we have a `categories` field with an array of category UUIDs and I want all pages having a certain category uuid. It works with using a like query (lets say 123-456 is a uuid) such as:

```
"SELECT * FROM [mgnl:page] p where p.[categories] like '%123-456%'
```

Is there a better approach without using (possible slow) `LIKE` queries to explicitly check for an intersection with the categories array? Are there any SET/ARRAY functions to use in where conditions for such filtering?

Answer (score 1):

In case of multifield values, you can put multiple WHERE statements like so:

```
SELECT * FROM [mgnl:content] AS p 
   WHERE p.[categories] = '415025c6-e4b5-4506-9384-34f428a52104'
   AND p.[categories] = 'e007e401-1bf8-4658-8293-b9c743784264'
```

This will return nodes in which `categories` (multivalue) property contains both IDs.